# Count minimum operations required to reach target number

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a function in JavaScript that takes an array of numbers, for example: `[5, 10, 18, 25, 30]` and then returns an array which contains the count of minimum operations required that it took to get from `0` to the target number, by only adding `1` or multiplying by `2`.

For example, from the array, the number `5` would return `4` because you'd do `0 + 1 = 1 x 2 = 2 x 2 = 4 + 1 = 5`.

If the array passed in was `[5,5,5]` the output array would be `[4,4,4]`.

I've looked around at potential solutions to this problem, some of which used iteration and others recursion. I found an answer for a similar question here [Code Review - Find sequence by adding 5 or multiplying by 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55838/find-sequence-by-adding-5-or-multiplying-by-3).

The only difference is this was adding 5 or multiplying by 2, and it starts from 1 as opposed to 0. I've attempted to adapt this solution to suit my needs, however, for some reason, the code will only ever `add 1` and never `times 2`. So, for the input `5` I am returned with `0 + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5` which obviously isn't the shortest solution.

Eventually I do need this to return an array, as the input will also be an array, however I'm struggling to even get this adaptation of the above answer to work, just with taking a single integer as a parameter.

When I pass `5` into this function I am returned with `5` instead of the shortest solution which is `4`, because it only ever `adds 1`.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
function findSequence(goal) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == goal) {
      return history;
    }
    if (start > goal) {
      return null;
    }
    return find(start + 1, "(" + history + " + 1)") ||
             find(start * 2, "(" + history + " * 2)");
  }
  return find(0, "0");
}
```

How can I make this work? I need to return the **shortest** sequence count to get from 0 to the target number by only **adding 1** or **multiplying 2**

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, all ones except the first need two steps, so `return goal.toString(2).split("").reduce((p, c) => +p + +c + 1);`.

Comment: From the question you linked to: **Keep in mind, this function does not necessarily find the shortest sequence of operations.** Why would you expect it to find the shortest when you change what you're adding and multiplying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
function findMoves(target)
{
    arr = [];
    while (target != 1)
    {
        if (target %2 == 0)
        {
            target /= 2;
            arr.unshift(target + " x " + 2);
            continue;
        }
        target -= 1;
        arr.unshift(target + " + " + 1);
    }
    arr.unshift("0 + 1");
    return arr;
}

res = findMoves(9);

console.log(
    "TotalMoves: " + res.length + "\n" + 
    "What moves: " + res.join(', '));
```

Prints:

```
TotalMoves: 5
What moves: 0 + 1, 1 x 2, 2 x 2, 4 x 2, 8 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easier to do in reverse. Start with your target and apply either a *minus 1* or a *divide by 2* until you hit zero. Once you've found that sequence, reverse it and use inverse ops (plus 1, times 2) to get back to your target.

```js
function getNext(num) {
  if (num === 0) return "end"
  if (num % 2 === 1) return "minus"
  return "div"
}

function makeSequence(num, ls) {
    const next = getNext(num);
    if (next === "end") return ls;
    ls.push(next)
    
    if (next === "div") return makeSequence(num/2, ls);
    if (next === "minus") return makeSequence(num-1, ls);
}

function reverseSequence(sqn) {
    return sqn.reverse().map(x => x === "minus" ? "plus" : "times");
}

var sqn = makeSequence(5, []);
var reversedSqn = reverseSequence(sqn)

console.log("Takes", reversedSqn.length, "steps with target of 5");
console.log("Steps are:", reversedSqn);     

var bigSqn = makeSequence(200, []);
var bigReversedSqn = reverseSequence(bigSqn);

console.log("Takes", bigReversedSqn.length, "steps with target of 200");
console.log("Steps are:", bigReversedSqn);
```